# Is there any information on when and how the old republic fell?

Tags: star-wars

In one Clone Wars episode it was mentioned that the Mandalorians entered the Jedi Temple and stole the Darksaber from there, when the Old Republic fell. Is there any canon info on when and how the Old Republic ended?

Comment: Which clone wars episode?

Comment: @amflare "The Mandalorian Plot" is the one he's referring it

Comment: @hyperdrive yepp tnx    I only knew the title of the episode in my language....and sadly they don't do 1:1 translations there most of the time -.-

Answer (score 6):

The Fall of the Old Republic was covered in greater depth before Disney de-canonized everything. I imagine that this line is actually what preserved some of that history since *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* and everything it said/showed remained canon. That said, bear in mind that canon is nothing but bare details now.

---

Roughly 1000 BBY, the Jedi were at war with the Mandalorians, Sith, and Zygerrian Slave Empire (these appear to be separate conflicts). At the time, the Jedi were the main military arm of the Republic, so as the various wars dragged on, and the Jedi suffered losses, the Republic, by extension, declined in power.

While 1000 BBY is when it all ended, the Jedi/Republic and the Sith had been at war for "thousands of years", during which time they traded control over the galaxy (it was not until the Galactic Republic that we all know and love that it had primary control over the entire known galaxy). It is also implied that the Mandalorians had been at war with The Republic for a similar amount of time, though this is unclear.

Anyway, towards the end of the conflict, a member of House Vizsla stole the Dark Saber, and the Sith captured Coruscant shortly thereafter. The Sith then had control of the galaxy at this point and held that for some time.

Obviously the Jedi couldn't let that stand, so they, and the remnants of The Old Republic, gathered their forces and drove the Sith off Coruscant and (at least appeared to) destroy them. The Jedi somehow managed to end their war with Mandalore which resulted in leaving the planet barren and lifeless.

At this point, having "destroyed" the Sith and won all their wars, the remnants of the Republic reformed itself into the Galactic Republic (presumably filling the power vacuum left by the defeated Sith Empire). The Jedi were then relegated to the role of peacekeepers, rather than military, and everything more or less stayed that way until the rise of the Empire under Darth Sidious.

---

For further reading, I recommend the [Old Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Republic) and [Fall of the Old Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fall_of_the_Old_Republic). A lot of my answer, as well as these articles, are drawn from passing lines in canon resources that are supplemented from knowledge of what was canon when these line were written. It makes for an interesting mash of myth and legend (lowercase L) in-universe. And out-of-universe most of this can be completely retconned at a moment's notice.

If you want a history of the Fall of the Old Republic in Legends (what was canon when the show was made) I recommend you ask a new question and leave this one to be updated as more canon information comes out.

Comment: If only the canon Old Republic time period was as rich and detailed as Legends